# the following error pops up when i import tensorflow in jupyter

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter

ImportError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 57 ---> 58 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 59

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 27 return _mod ---> 28 _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 29 del swig_import_helper

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper() 23 try: ---> 24 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) 25 finally:

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details) 241 else: --> 242 return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) 243 elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file) 341 name=name, loader=loader, origin=path) --> 342 return _load(spec) 343

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError Traceback (most recent call last) in ----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py in 39 import sys as _sys 40 ---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util 42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader 43

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_init_.py in 48 import numpy as np 49 ---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow 51 52 # Protocol buffers

~\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 67 for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace 68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc() ---> 69 raise ImportError(msg) 70 71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Abalreddy\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * File "C:\Users\Abalreddy\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Users\Abalreddy\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) File "C:\Users\Abalreddy\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) File "C:\Users\Abalreddy\anaconda3\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please add more details to your question- what you've tried, what you're currently using, and what you've found when researching?

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this error for instant use just create a new `conda environment with python 3.x` and install necessary libraries.

For future use please check if your python is added in path variable.

installing visual studio 2015-2019 x86 and x64 from here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
(this also works most of the times)

Answer (score 0):

Try pip installing it in jupyter itself.

`!pip install tensorflow`